# Activating a sequence of the binary variables in a multi-dimensional array

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, logical-constraints

Suppose we have an array of binary variables $\{x_{i,t,n}, \ \forall i \in I, t \in T, n \in N \}$. If we want to define a condition as, if any of $x_{i,t,n} = 1$ in an arbitrary index $i$, then the rest of the bigger index $i$ should be one. (E.g. if the card of index I would be six, then one of the possible solutions would be $\{0,0,1,1,1,1\}$. (For simplicity, I omitted the sets $T$ and $N$). I know there is a constraint as $x_{i,t,n} \leq x_{i+1,t,n}$, but as far as I test in some problems, it sorts the variables from the first position. For example in the scheduling problem when we want to deploy the resources respectively. Actually, I am not sure it can be used in general at all. I tried to write that in the following form, and I would like to know other insights regarding that.

$$ ((x_{i} \implies(x_{j} \land x_{k})) \bigvee  (x_{j} \implies(\lnot x_{i} \land x_{k})) \bigvee (x_{k} \implies(\lnot x_{i} \land \lnot x_{j}))) \quad \forall i,j,k \in I: (i\lt j \lt k) $$

Comment: Is $I$ a set of consecutive integers?

Comment: Dear @RobPratt, it may be or may not. For some of the examples it is and for others it is a set of strings. e.g. jobs ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introduce an ordering $\text{ord}: I \to \{1,\dots,|I|\}$ and impose
$$x_i \le x_j$$
for all $i\in I$ and $j\in I$ such that $\text{ord}_i + 1 = \text{ord}_j$.

An alternative, less efficient, approach with $O(|I|^2)$ constraints is
$$x_i \le x_j$$
for all $i\in I$ and $j\in I$ such that $\text{ord}_i < \text{ord}_j$.

Comment: Dear @RobPratt, thank you so much for your attention. Would you please, how is it possible to use this when the set $I$ is strings?

Comment: And also may I have your insight about what I proposed?

Comment: The set $I$ can have arbitrary types (numbers, strings, tuples, etc.).  You just need to define the ord mapping to indicate what it means for one index $i$ to be higher or lower than another.  For strings, alphabetical order seems natural, but does that match your business rule?

Comment: Regarding what you proposed, if the order mapping is the identity $\text{ord}(i)=i$, then I think you meant $\land$ instead of $\lor$.  But then the resulting proposition would then just be a complicated way to express $x_i \implies x_j$.

Comment: thanks. I can do what you proposed. 

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you mean by $\land$ instead of $\lor$? Would you please elaborate more.

Comment: Do you mean is something like this: $x \implies (x \lor x)$?

Comment: No, I mean to change the two $\bigvee$ symbols (logical OR) to $\bigwedge$ (logical AND) because each of the three clauses must hold independently.

Comment: That's great. 

Comment: Glad to help.  Minor quibble: that correction of $\bigvee$ to $\bigwedge$ would not still prohibit $(1,0)$ in the $|I|=2$ case because there is no $i<j<k$.